# Beamer compiles but does not produce any output

Tags: beamer, xetex

I'm trying to make slides with the `beamer` package.  When I compile, it finishes successfully but does not produce any pages other than the title slide.  When I remove the `\maketitle`, then no pages are written!  TeX ends with "No pages of output."  The surprising bit is, just this morning I made another presentation with no problems at all.  To me this feels like a problem with my installation, but I have not fiddled with the installation in any manner since this morning.  I'm using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[presentation,smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\institute{Institute}

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\author{Suvayu}
\date{\today}
\title{Testing mysterious no output}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle
\begin{frame}[label=sec:orgheadline1]{First slide}
  I should be printed
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=sec:orgheadline3]{Second slide}
  So should I
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I have to finish this by tomorrow.  Any immediate help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:` messes up the argument.
Leave it out or wrap the label in `{}`:

This works:

```
\documentclass[presentation,smaller]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgheadline1}]{First slide}
  I should be printed
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this one too:

```
\documentclass[presentation,smaller]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=orgheadline1]{First slide}
  I should be printed
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```